# Extend axis on oxyplot

Tags: c#, charts, oxyplot

I use oxyplot and I generated that graph which is pretty good but I'd like to keep the same value on the Y axes (0 to 1)

I use that code but it is always just over the top value (and the bottom value)

```
model.Axes.Add(new OxyPlot.Axes.LinearAxis
                {
                    Position = OxyPlot.Axes.AxisPosition.Left,
                    StartPosition = 0,
                    EndPosition = 1
                });
```

How can I resolve that issue ?

the only way i found is to put a blank line on 0Y and 1Y

[image]

Comment: I believe you're looking for `Minimum = 0, Maximum = 1`.

Comment: Thank you a lot. Can you write it as an answer ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Axis range can be set using the `Minimum` and `Maximum` properties, like this:

```
model.Axes.Add(new OxyPlot.Axes.LinearAxis
            {
                Position = OxyPlot.Axes.AxisPosition.Left,
                Minimum= 0,
                Maximum= 1
            });
```